# Jmeter CSVRead in JSON assertion

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Is there a way that the `CSVRead` function can skip the first line of the CSV file?

This is my current code in the JSON Assertion
`[${__CSVRead(temp_tax_rate.csv,0)},${__CSVRead(temp_tax_rate.csv,0)},${__CSVRead(temp_tax_rate.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(temp_tax_rate.csv,next)}]`

I just need to skip the first line because the first line of the CSV is the header.

I'm quite new to JMeter any instruction that might help solve the problem would be super.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[__CSVRead](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) support `next` for going to next line, so you can add it before:

```
${__CSVRead(temp_tax_rate.csv,next)}
```

> Column number The column number in the file. 0 = first column, 1 = second etc. "next" - go to next line of file. *ALIAS - open a file and assign it to the alias

Comment: I cant follow this suggestion because im running my test in a loop and it will skip a line even after skipping the header

Comment: @maxim you can add code under Once only controller

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your file has only one "column" the easiest would be reading it using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

- `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(1),)}` - read 2nd line from file
- `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(2),)}` - read 3rd file from file
- etc.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I tried doing this but the JSON assertion wont accept it.